# Deploying apache Kafka on Azure

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, azure-aks

I read about, Event HUB, HDinsights and deploying Kafka on IaaS in Availability Set.

I need to know which are the requirements to implementing Kafka on AKS.

How can I know how many nodes needed? And also want to know how to calculate billing.

Finally to compare the three that I mentioned vs Kafka on AKS

Comment: HDInsights is more than just Kafka. It wouldn't be a fair comparison, and would be the most expensive option. Besides that, a Kafka Cluster can be a single machine, so what are your requirements?

Comment: Sorry, the only information about requirements is that the Kafka will receive 13millons events per month

Comment: How large is each event? Do those events need to be replicated? Have you tried benchmarking a single broker to see what throughput is possible?

Answer (score 0):

The number of nodes depends on your requirements in terms of load, throughput and so on. If you are going to choose Apache Kafka on AKS I would suggest using the Strimzi project (https://strimzi.io/) to deploy it pretty easily. I also wrote a simple demo for a session I had about this (https://github.com/ppatierno/strimzi-aks).

Comment: Maybe note you're working for RedHat, which develops Strimzi? Otherwise, why not EventHub or the others?

Comment: He was asking for Kafka on AKS so I suggested Strimzi. It all depends on his requirements which are not in the question. Of course, EventHub could be a solution with the Kafka supported protocol ... even Kafka on HDInsight.